# Issue when transforming spatial data in R - shapefile

Tags: r

I am trying to obtain a plot with the ice presence in the Arctic.
I am using a shapefile obtained from: https://nsidc.org/data/masie/

```
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
library(plyr)
library(ggmap)
library(dismo)
library(raster)
library(plyr)  

ICE <- readOGR(".", "masie_ice_r00_v01_2018094_4km")
plot(ICE)
```

[image]

```
ICE_WGS84 <- spTransform(ICE, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
plot(ICE_WGS84, axes=T)
```

[image]

As you can see, the polygons seem to be split and I would like to fix this issue. Any suggestions?
I would like to project the ice presence on a google map.

```
mapImage <- get_map(location = c(lon = -160, lat = 66),
                    color = "color",
                    source = "google",
                    zoom = 4)

ggmap(mapImage) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long,
                   y = lat,
                   group = group),
               data = ICE_WGS84,
               fill="white") +
  labs(x = "Longitude",
       y = "Latitude")
```

Thank you in advance!

I would like to obtain something similar to this (without the polygon issue...)
[image]

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're required output is; is it a `.png` of the map, or a `.shp` of that specific region of ice?

Comment: If I can plot my data points on the (google) map with the ice presence, I will save the all as a png

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is probably due to polygons surrounding the North Pole, and the plots are getting confused about what's inside and what's outside the Polygon.

Fortunately, as you want to use a Google Map, their plotting library is quite clever and can resolve this.

And doubly fortunately, my `googleway` package lets you plot Google Maps

---

Notes:

1. In this example I'm using `library(sf)` to read and manipulate the spatial data (it's the 'latest' spatial library in R).
2. To use Google Maps you need an API key

---

```
library(sf)
library(googleway)

sf <- sf::st_read("~/Downloads/maise_ice_r00_4km/masie_ice_r00_v01_2018094_4km.shp")
sf <- sf::st_transform(sf, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")


set_key("your_map_api_key")

google_map() %>%
    add_polygons(data = sf, fill_colour = "#FFFFFF", fill_opacity = 0.6)
```

[image]

---

You can add other data onto the map, for example as markers, and use `htmlwidgets::saveWidget` and `webshot::webshot` to save a static image of the map

```
df_other_data <- data.frame(
    lon = c(-42, -60, 42.2), 
    lat = c(70, 70.1, 70.2)
    )

## assigning the map to an object `g` , and specifying the zoom & view options
g <- google_map(zoom = 6) %>%
    add_polygons(data = sf, fill_colour = "#FFFFFF", fill_opacity = 0.6, update_map_view = F) %>%
    add_markers(df_other_data)


setwd("~/Desktop/")

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(g, file = "ArcticMap.html")
webshot::webshot(url = "file:///Users/.../Desktop/ArcticMap.html",
                                 file = "ArcticMap.jpg")
## replace the '...' with your saved .html file path
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. i have an issue when I run your code, i don't obtain any map? I got an API key through this website (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) but when I put it instead of "your_map_api_key" and run the following line - nothing happens. Do you need to call the set_key in the following line? Thanks

Comment: what do you see if you just do `google_map(key =  )` (inserting your actual key into the key argument)

Comment: Nothing happens - the viewer tab (in R studio) is blank - Just to be sure, I need to add the quotation marks for my API key, right?

Comment: @H_Frouin - yes, it will be like `google_map(key = "AIzaSyxxxxx")`. which version of RStudio are you using? If you press the 'show in new window' button it should open in  browser; does this work?

Comment: Version 1.1.383. Oh I see, it opens as a googlemap - the issue is that I need to use the googlemap as a layer because I want to add some dots (data) on it and save the map as a png. Is it possible using googleway to set up some boundaries and save as a shapefile?

Comment: If you update your RStudio you should see the map in the viewer window directly.

Comment: and are you saving a shape file (`.shp`) or a `.png`?

Comment: I updated R studio - the map still doesn't show up in the viewer window directly. I am trying to save the ice presence as a shapefile (but I didn't success ....).

Comment: Ok - i edited my question and added the kind of map that i would like to obtain. Sorry, if I am not clear.